# Cronometro Progressivo Atualizando div

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como fazer um cronômetro progressivo, visível na tela e que a cada 60 segundos atualizasse uma `div` que o código buscou de um outro arquivo PHP.

Se possível, gostaria que **hora** **minutos** e **segundos** fossem imprimidos separadamente para melhor posicionamento na tela.

Abaixo segue o segundo arquivo que vou chamar de 60 em 60 segundos:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$d = date('d');
$m = date('m');
$y = date('Y');
$h = date('H');
$i = date('i');
$s = date('s');

#setando a primeira data  10/01/2008 
$dia1 = mktime(22,45,00,04,04,2019);

#setando segunda data 10/02/2008
$dia2 = mktime($h,$i,$s,$m,$d,$y);  

#armazenando o valor da subtracao das datas
$d3 = ($dia2-$dia1);

#usando o round para arrendondar os valores
#converter o tempo em dias
$dias = round(($d3/60/60/24));

#converter o tempo em horas
$hrs = round(($d3/60/60));

#converter o tempo em minutos
$mins = round(($d3/60));

#exibindo  minutos
echo '<b>2Quilos: </b>'.$mins."<br>";
```

Comment: Fabio, como está até o momento o que vc fez?

Comment: coloquei o codigo acima do arquivo que vai ser atualizado pelo cronometro. Essa parte do cronometro eu não sei fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cronometro.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(function () {
            /* Disparando requisicao ao carregar */
            getValue();
            setChronometer();
            /* Disparando requisicao a cada 60 segundos */
            setInterval(
                function(){
                    getValue();
                    setChronometer();
                }, 60000
            );
            /* Usando moment.js */
            var interval = setInterval(
                function() {
                    var newMoment = moment();
                    $('#time').html(newMoment.format('HH:mm:ss'));
                    $('#h').html(newMoment.format('HH'));
                    $('#m').html(newMoment.format('mm'));
                    $('#s').html(newMoment.format('ss'));
                }, 100
            );
        });
        /**
        * Recupera um objetoc JSON
        * @return void
        */
        function getValue(){
            var newMoment = moment();
            $.post("cronometro.php",{},
                function (resp) {
                    $('#variavel').html(resp.variavel);
                    $('#last_update').html(newMoment.format('HH:mm:ss'));
                }
            );
        }
        /**
        * Contador progressivo (60 segundos)
        * @return void
        */
        function setChronometer(){
            var counter = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(
                function() {
                    counter++;
                    $('#counter').html(counter);
                    if (counter == 60) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 1000
            );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Vari&aacute;vel</td>
            <td>&Uacute;ltima atualiza&ccedil;&atilde;o</td>
            <td>Rel&oacute;gio</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="variavel"></div></td>
            <td><div id="last_update"></div></td>
            <td><div id='time'></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>hora</td>
            <td>minuto</td>
            <td>segundo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="h"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="m"></div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div id="s"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Contando 60 segundos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="counter"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**cronometro.php**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$d = date('d');
$m = date('m');
$y = date('Y');
$h = date('H');
$i = date('i');
$s = date('s');

#setando a primeira data  10/01/2008 
$dia1 = mktime(22,45,00,04,04,2019);

#setando segunda data 10/02/2008
$dia2 = mktime($h,$i,$s,$m,$d,$y);

#armazenando o valor da subtracao das datas
$d3 = ($dia2-$dia1);

#usando o round para arrendondar os valores
#converter o tempo em dias
$dias = round(($d3/60/60/24));

#converter o tempo em horas
$hrs = round(($d3/60/60));

#converter o tempo em minutos
$mins = round(($d3/60));

#exibindo  minutos
$variavel = "<b>2Quilos:&nbsp;</b>".$mins."<br>";
$last_update = $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;

$array = [
    'variavel' => $variavel
];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Parceiro é isso mesmo só o cronometro que não está rodando e queria o timer separado <div>hora<div> <div>min<div> e <div>segundos<div>

Comment: Editado para mostrar um relógio (cronômetro?!) e hora minutos e segundos em `divs` separadas no doc `html` usando `moment.js`.